# Tkinter in python 2.7 to 3.6

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, tkinter, python-3.6

This is about some code snippets I was trying out.
They were in [python-2.7](/questions/tagged/python-2.7) so I changed the one line I found that needed to be changed:

```
from Tkinter import *
```

to

```
from tkinter import *
```

well... I was ***VERY*** wrong on that.
I guess some moduals got removed between [python-2.7](/questions/tagged/python-2.7) and [python-3](/questions/tagged/python-3)???
well it causes `modualNotFoundError` whenever I try to run it.
these are the moduals:

```
tkFileDialog
tkMessageBox
```

*Note: I will update this when i find more [tkinter](/questions/tagged/tkinter) [libraries](/questions/tagged/libraries) that are outdated*

Comment: not removed, just renamed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those modules are named now `filedialog` and `messagebox`.

You can check the [tkinter documentation on modules](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#tkinter-modules) for more information

**Update:**

See this example for tkinter on python 3.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox, filedialog

window_size = '200x100'

top = Tk()
top.geometry(window_size)

def msgbox_hello():
    messagebox.showinfo('Messagebox title', 'Messagebox content')

def filedialog_world():
    file_name = filedialog.askopenfilename()

    # Display file name
    if file_name:
        messagebox.showinfo(
            'Selected file name',
            'You selected "{}"'.format(file_name))


B1 = Button(top, text="msgbox", command=msgbox_hello)
B1.pack(side=TOP, fill='x')

B2 = Button(top, text="filedialog", command=filedialog_world)
B2.pack(side=TOP, fill='x')

B3 = Button(top, text="Exit", command=exit)
B3.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill='x')

top.mainloop()
```

Comment: Keep in mind that you can still use python 2.7 for your application (usually with `python2` if you're using linux).

Comment: I tryed it and it didnt work. are you sure this is for [tag:python-3.6]?